# Javascript Regular Expression to search a multiline textarea for an expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say there is a textarea with the following value ('*' being used as a bullet point):

```
*south
*north
*west
```

I want to be able to automatically generate an array of these words using Regular Expression, like this.

```
["south","north","west"]
```

Below is the expression I tried.

```
/\*.*/gm.exec(text)
```

Unfortunately it returns this instead.

```
["*south"]
```

Apparently, RegExp recognizes there is a line break such that it only returns the first item, yet it doesn't pick up the 2nd and 3rd lines.

```
/\*.*/gm.exec('*south \n *north')
```

This also has the same result.

Comment: I have just noticed you may have leading whitespaces, and I suggest using `/^\s*\*\s*(.*)/gm` regex with `RegExp#exec`. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the regex engine to match at the beginning of a line with `^`, and *capture* the part after the first `*` with a pair of unescaped parentheses. Then, you can use [`RegExp#exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) in a loop, and get the value you need in Group 1. The [`^\s*\*\s*(.*)` regex](https://regex101.com/r/cL0vO5/3) matches:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `/m` multiline modifier)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace symbols
- `\*` - a literal asterisk
- `\s*` - again, optional whitespace(s)
- `(.*)` - zero or more characters other than a newline.

```js
var re = /^\s*\*\s*(.*)/gm; 
var str = '*south\n *north\n* west ';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

**Another solution:**

Split with newline (a regex is possible here if there can be `\r` or `\n`) and then get rid of the initial `*`:

```js
var str = '*south\n*north\n*west ';
var res = [];
str.split(/[\r\n]+/).forEach(function(e) {
      res.push(e.replace(/^\s*\*\s*/, '')); 
  });
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to run a loop.

```
var re = /\*(.*)/gm; 
var str = '*south\n*north\n*west ';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {


    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/11

or you an split by `(?=\*)`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/12

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. I wish I could mark multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

@VKS solution works, but if it is not mandatory to use regex then try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wxjn0yw/)

```
<textarea id="textA1"></textarea>

$( "#textA1" ).blur( function(){

   var value = $( this ).val();
   console.log( value.split( "\n" ) );

} )
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a requirement to use regex, but this would have a good solution otherwise.